# Purpose of 要's location in 今天晚上老板要和我们一起加班。

Tags: grammar, sentence-structure

> 今天晚上老板**要**和我们一起加班。

What purpose does 要 have here (in this specific location)?
I thought it would be;

> 今天晚上老板和我们一起**要**加班。

I know 要 also means 'to do smth' so I get why it's needed, but why in that specific position? Because I thought 要 came before the verb.

Comment: The short answer is 要=will.

Comment: @trisct But still. Can't you just put 要 before 加班 to mean the same thing? (The boss and us, together, WILL work overtime.)

Comment: I see what you mean. But that doesn't sound natural. And I doubt it that this can be explained by grammar.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The usual 一起 grammar structure is

> Subj. + 一起 + Verb + Obj.
> <sub>[Expressing "together" with "yiqi"](https://resources.allsetlearning.com/chinese/grammar/Expressing_%22together%22_with_%22yiqi%22)</sub>

Adding 要 after 一起 interferes with this structure: it's possible to misinterpret 要 as the verb.

#### Comparison

There's actually three places 要 (which [has a few meanings](https://resources.allsetlearning.com/chinese/grammar/Auxiliary_verb_%22yao%22_and_its_multiple_meanings)) can be added:

1. > 今天晚上老板**要**和我们一起加班。
   > Tonight, [the] boss **[wants to/needs to/is going to]** *work overtime together with us*.

So we have:

- the subject is 老板 = "[the] boss",
- the verb is 要, and
- and what they want to do is 和我们一起加班 = "to work overtime together with us".

This seems unproblematic, and probably the most natural.

2. > 今天晚上老板和我们**要**一起加班。
   > Tonight, [the] boss and us **[want to/need to/are going to]** *work overtime together*.

So we have:

- the subject is 老板和我们 = "[the] boss and us",
- the verb is 要 = "want to", and
- and what they want to do is 一起加班 = "to work overtime together".

This also seems unproblematic.

3. > 今天晚上老板和我们一起**要**加班。
   > Tonight, [the] boss and us together **[want to/need to/are going to]** *work overtime*.

This one is more complicated:

- the subject is 老板和我们 = "[the] boss and us",
- the verb is 一起要 = "together want to" or "together need to" or "together [are] going to" (??), and
- and what they together [want to/need to/are going to] do is 加班 = "to work overtime".

I feel this one is ambiguous because what follows 一起 is 要, so it's possible to interpret 一起 as applying to 要 and not necessarily to 加班.  Something in English to indicate the difference:

> We don't work at the same company, but we're together wanting to work overtime to save money for an upcoming concert.

But realistically, it's a very contrived interpretation.  So I don't believe the Chinese here is wrong, it just sounds a bit weird.

#### Baidu

Compare the Baidu search results:

- [`"要一起加班"`](https://www.baidu.com/s?wd=%22%E8%A6%81%E4%B8%80%E8%B5%B7%E5%8A%A0%E7%8F%AD%22) (19) vs. [`"一起要加班"`](https://www.baidu.com/s?wd=%22%E4%B8%80%E8%B5%B7%E8%A6%81%E5%8A%A0%E7%8F%AD%22) (0),
- [`"要一起做饭"`](https://www.baidu.com/s?wd=%22%E8%A6%81%E4%B8%80%E8%B5%B7%E5%81%9A%E9%A5%AD%22) (29) vs. [`"一起要做饭"`](https://www.baidu.com/s?wd=%22%E4%B8%80%E8%B5%B7%E8%A6%81%E5%81%9A%E9%A5%AD%22) (2),
- [`"要一起逛街"`](https://www.baidu.com/s?&wd=%22%E8%A6%81%E4%B8%80%E8%B5%B7%E9%80%9B%E8%A1%97%22) (62) vs. [`"一起要逛街"`](https://www.baidu.com/s?&wd=%22%E4%B8%80%E8%B5%B7%E8%A6%81%E9%80%9B%E8%A1%97%22) (1),
- [`"要一起学习"`](https://www.baidu.com/s?&wd=%22%E8%A6%81%E4%B8%80%E8%B5%B7%E5%AD%A6%E4%B9%A0%22) (76,000) vs. [`"一起要学习"`](https://www.baidu.com/s?&wd=%22%E4%B8%80%E8%B5%B7%E8%A6%81%E5%AD%A6%E4%B9%A0%22) (17).

(The number 76,000 is likely hugely inaccurate, but there's a lot.)

We consistently see that `一起[2-character verb]` does not want a 要 in between.

Answer (score 1):

When 要 is used to mean "do something", it usually means "will do sth" or "want to do sth", and also sometimes "need to do sth".

In your original sentence, 要 can mean both "will" or "want to" depending on the context. See the following examples.

> 今天事情比较多，所以今天晚上老板要和我们一起加班 (There is too much to do today, hence the boss **will** join us in working overtime tonight).
>
> 老板想知道我们加班时到底有没有认真干活，所以今天晚上老板要和我们一起加班 (The boss wants to know whether we are taking the overtime seriously and **wants to** join us tonight).

As for the position, I am not sure whether there is an explanation involving grammar. The second one does not sound natural while the first one does.

I can come up with an example where 要 is placed right before the verb, only with slight modification to your sentence:

> 今天晚上老板和我们一样要加班 (The boss has to work overtime tonight just like us).

Comment: The grammar was a bit lost on me since I read that 要 comes before the verb but I guess, at times, it's just about which one sounds better.

Comment: @QuarterOne There is one possible explanation. Note that 和我们一起 is used to describe the verb 加班 and therefore you should think of 和我们一起加班 as an integral part.

Comment: The examples clarified it to an extent. Sorta like the boss wants/is going to do something so you just attach 要 to 老板.(The boss is GOING TO join us,together, we'll work overtime).  I understand now. Thanks!

Comment: @QuarterOne Whereas in my last example sentence, 和我们一样 describes the boss: the boss is in the same situation as us where he has to work overtime.

Answer (score 0):

Think about this sentence first:

> 今天晚上老板要和我们一起. // The boss will/want to be with us tonight

To do what? *加班，work overtime.*

> 今天晚上老板要和我们一起  **加班**。//The boss will be with us tonight **to work overtime**.

Taking 加班 as a complement might help you.